# How to automatically detect encoding of the tex-file?

Tags: languages, package-writing, input-encodings

I have a custom `.sty`-file in `cp1251` encoding which is defines `\RequirePackage[cp1251]{inputenc}`. I use it for compile with `pdflatex` in the same encoding, But when I try to compile some file with other encoding, say `utf8` I, of course, get an errors. 
How my package can automatically check the file encoding and hence redefine parameters of `\RequirePackage[<current file encoding>]{inputenc}`?

Briefly, I need something like

```
\if@CurrentFileEncoding=utf8
       \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
       \RequirePackage{literat}
\else
       \RequirePackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
       \RequirePackage{<someotherpackage>}
```

Comment: Have a look at `selinput`

Comment: Unless it is a private package loading `inputenc` should be left to the user IMHO. Personally I wouldn't bother and would just leave it...

Comment: It is almost always better _not_ to force the document encoding. The package can be written to just use classic ascii input with no input encoding dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `selinput`; for this particular case, a cyrillic letter can be used, together with a restricted set of encodings to look for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputEncodingList{utf8,cp1251}
\SelectInputMappings{
  cyrd={д},
}

\begin{document}
\inputencodingname
\end{document}
```

If the file is encoded in UTF-8, compiling it will produce

> utf8

If it's encoded in CP1251,

> cp1251

will be produced.

However, your problem is different and not really solvable.

If your package has, say

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Глава}
```

and is encoded in CP1251, there will be *no* way to use this in a UTF-8 encoded document, because TeX uses the input encoding only when *expanding macros*. It is completely irrelevant when TeX stores a definition.

In this case, `\chaptername` will expand to the sequence of characters

```
<C3><EB><E0><E2><E0>
```

(each `<..>` denotes a character code) with category code 13, that will be invalid in a UTF-8 encoded document.

You could use

```
\RequirePackage[utf8,cp1251]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{cp1251}
```

in the `sergiokapone.sty` file and

```
\protected@edef\chaptername{Глава}
```

in the code, that would make LaTeX expand `\chaptername` to

```
\IeC{\CYRG}\IeC{\cyrl}\IeC{\cyra}\IeC{\cyrv}\IeC{\cyra}
```

which is independent of the encoding, and the main document would use

```
\usepackage{sergiokapone}
\inputencoding{utf8} % or cp1251
```

or, possibly, `selinput` as shown before.

This is however not what I'd recommend. The best way to proceed is to make `.sty` files encoding independent; the above `\renewcommand` should be

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\CYRG\cyrl\cyra\cyrv\cyra}
```